# How can I view the top 20 answerers for a tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I was notified today that I now have the ability to [edit tag wikis](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit-tag-wiki). Of course, to edit a tag wiki, I have to fulfill one of two requirements:

- have a total score of 100 or more for the tag (thus having earned the bronze badge for that tag)
- be in the top 20 answerers for the tag

At the moment, I do not qualify for any tag per the first criterion. How can I tell whether I qualify per the second one?

Comment: I think there is an OR between those two conditions, you need either 100 upvotes OR be in the top 20 anwerers.

Comment: You should be able to propose an edit to a tag wiki now even without fulfilling those requirements. Feel free to improve some tag wikis

Comment: @Fabian: Correct. Note I said "one of two requirements". :)

Comment: @Fabian: Indeed. I was more interested in poking around to see if I'd entered the top 20 in any tags. I didn't expect to have done so yet, but was curious if the information was available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured this out:

- Click [a tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2) to view it.
- Click on the small [top users](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/starcraft-2/topusers) link in the header of the page.

Going to leave this up rather than delete it since it hadn't already been answered.